# Run function on every prompt line with .bash_profile editing

Tags: bash, terminal

I have the following `PS1` command in my `.bash_profile`:

```
PS1="$(svn info 2>&1 | grep 'Relative URL' | awk '{print $NF}')"
```

So that the output of this command is presented in the prompt line.

**But it is run once I start the terminal and it just stays there**, instead of changing while I navigate through my directories. So it runs once and is left there.

How can I make it change as I am navigating my directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   PROMPT_COMMAND
          If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
          primary prompt.


$ PROMPT_COMMAND=date
Sun Feb 21 13:35:21 EST 2016
$ echo a
a
Sun Feb 21 13:35:23 EST 2016
$ echo b
b
Sun Feb 21 13:35:24 EST 2016
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`date +%H:%M`\ $\ '
13:35 $ sleep 60
13:36 $
```